# Drupal: page specific theming without node-id

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am adding a page with a node-id and earlier I was using "page--node--node-id.tpl.php" template to customize the node/page. However, I accidentally deleted that node, and now I am unable to create that node with particular nid node. I want to know how to customize the specific page as each page his unique title.

Comment: You can create new node, and change it's nid directly in database. Use PhpMyAdmin or similar tool. Not the cleanest solution but if you know what nid was used before (and you do, since template is namend by it) it's pretty safe. Check for "node" table.

Comment: Or even simpler. Just create new node, see what is it's nid and rename template so new nid will replace old one. Don't forget to clear the cache!

Answer (score 1):

Use page--node.tpl.php for all the nodes instead of each template otherwise use 
node--[node-type].tpl.php for specifc node content type template

There is another smart step to create content type template with your own specific name by following below code

function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

if (isset($vars['node'])) {

$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $vars['node']->type);

}

}

In above case If node content type is "article" then the template suggestion will be "page--article.tpl.php".

Answer (score 1):

Create template file page--nodetype.tpl.php in your theme directory.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I guess safest way is to create a new content type and add the template "page--content-type.tpl.php". its easy when you deploy your project from local setup to live setup. The disadvantage of having node specific template page is if you delete that node mistakenly then drupal will not allow you to create a new node with specific nid (which is very sad i don't know why drupal doesn't allow it even via programming commands).